# asm pointers, what am I getting wrong?

Tags: pointers, assembly

```
int sort(int* list)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov esi, [list];
            mov eax, dword ptr[esi + edx * 4];   store pointer to eax?
            mov edi, dword ptr[esi + 4 + edx * 4]; store pointer to edi?
            jmp swap;

swap:
        push dword ptr[esi + edx * 4];
        mov dword ptr[esi + edx * 4], edi;      
        pop dword ptr[esi + 4 + edx * 4];
```

This is a portion of my homework code, it works properly but I want to know how I can change my swap to use registers instead of dword ptrs. I initially had:

```
swap: (none of this works... values remain unchanged. why? =[ )
            push eax; supposed to push value pointed to?
            mov eax, edi; supposed to change value pointed at by eax? 
            pop edi; supposed to pop pushed value into edi pointer location?
```

but this doesn't actually swap anything, the array passed in doesn't change. How can I get rewrite my code so that the swap statement looks like this? I tried putting [] around eax in the above swap statement but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Doesn't a swap need at least three instructions? A load, an exchange, and a store?

Comment: Is that supposed to swap the values without pushing/popping? I was trying to figure out how to swap with push/pop using pointers.

Comment: (That said, exchange is expensive, and GCC [prefers four cheap instructions](https://goo.gl/SRtGrz).)

Comment: Without push-pop : swap : `mov [esi + edx * 4] , edi` , `mov [esi + 4 + edx * 4] , eax` . Remember your stored the values in eax and edi before swap.

Comment: You can store the value to the stack by pushing it, then change the value and pop the stored value into the other location. This swap works, I just want to know how to make it look neater using registers (the second form of swap versus the first one I typed out).

Comment: In your second version you're copying two values from the array into a couple of registers, and then swapping those copies. So it's no wonder that the array isn't modified.

Answer (score 0):

With three instructions (as Kerrek SB said) and only one register (EAX):

```
int exchange ()
{ int list[5] = {1,5,2,4,3};
  __asm { mov edx, 0
          lea esi, list
          // SWAP WITH THREE INSTRUCTIONS.
            mov  eax, [esi + edx * 4]
            xchg [esi + 4 + edx * 4], eax
            mov  [esi + edx * 4], eax
            // NOW LIST =  {5,1,2,4,3};
        }
}
```

Or, with the array as parameter :

```
int exchange ( int * list )
{  __asm { mov edx, 0
           mov esi, list
           // SWAP WITH THREE INSTRUCTIONS.
           mov  eax, [esi + edx * 4]
           xchg [esi + 4 + edx * 4], eax
           mov  [esi + edx * 4], eax
           // LIST =  {5,1,2,4,3};
         }
}
```

And this is how to call it :

```
int list[5] = {1,5,2,4,3};
exchange( list );
```

Comment: Bear in mind that x86 `xchg` has an implied lock prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the confusion might be how your function receives its inputs.  If you write your whole function in asm, rather than inline with MSVC-specific syntax, then [the ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) tells you that your parameters will be on the stack (for 32bit x86 code).  http://www.agner.org/optimize/ has a calling-conventions doc, too, covering the various different calling conventions for x86 and x86-64.

Anyway.

`xchg` might seem like exactly the instruction you want for doing a swap.  If you really do need to exchange the contents of two registers, it's very similar in performance to the 3 `mov` instructions that would otherwise be required, but without the temporary register needed.  However, it's somewhat rare to actually need to swap two registers, rather than just overwrite one, or save the old value somewhere else.  Also, 3 `mov reg, reg` will be faster on Ivy Bridge / Haswell, because they don't need an execution unit for it; they just handle it in the register rename stage (with 0 latency).

For swapping the contents of two memory locations, it's at least 25 times slower than using `mov` for loads/stores, due to the implicit `LOCK` prefix forcing the CPU to make sure all other cores get the update right away, instead of just writing to L1 cache.

What you need to do is 2 loads, and 2 stores.

The simplest form (2 loads, 2 stores, works in the general case) will be

```
# void swap34(int *array)

swap34:
 # 32bit: mov edi, [esp+4]   # [esp] has the return address
 # 64bit windows: mov rdi, rcx  # first function arg comes in rcx
# array pointer in rdi, assuming 64bit SystemV (Linux) ABI.
mov eax, [rdi+8]    # load array[3]
mov ebx, [rdi+12]   # load array[4]
mov [rdi+12], eax   # store array[4] = tmp1
mov [rdi+8],  ebx   # store array[3] = tmp2
ret
```

With more complex addressing modes (e.g. `[rdi+rax*4]`, you could swap `list[rax]` with `list[rbx]`.)

If the memory locations are adjacent, and you can load both at once with a wider load, and rotate to swap.  e.g.

```
# int *array in rdi
mov  rax, [rdi+4]  # load 2nd and 3rd 32bit element
rol  rax, 32       # rotate left by half the reg width
mov  [rdi+4], rax  # store back to the same place
```

I believe those 3 instructions will actually run faster than `rol  [rdi+4], 32`.  (rotate with memory operand and `imm8` count is 4 uops on Intel Sandybridge, throughput of 1 per 2 cycles.  The load/rot/store is 3 uops, and should sustain 1 per cycle.  The memory-operand version uses fewer instruction bytes.  It doesn't leave either value in a register, though.  Usually in real code, you're going to want to do something further with one of the values.)

The only other way I can think of to use fewer instructions would if you had `rsi` and `rdi` pointing at the values to be swapped.  Then you could

```
movd  eax, [rdi]  ;  DON'T DO THIS,
movsd    ; string-move, 4B version.  copies [rsi] to [rdi]
movd  [rsi-4], eax ;  IT'S SLOW
```

This would be a lot slower than 2 loads / 2 stores, and `movsd` increments `rsi` and `rdi`.  Saving an instruction here actually makes for slower code, and code that uses MORE space in the uop cache on recent Intel design.  (A `movsd` without a `rep` prefix is never a good choice.)

Another instruction that reads from one memory location and writes to another is `pop` or `push` with a memory operand, but that only works if the stack pointer was already pointing to one of the values you wanted to swap, and you didn't care about changing the stack pointer.

Don't go messing with the stack pointer.  You can in theory save the stack pointer somewhere, and use it as another GP register for a loop where you're out of registers, but only if you don't need to call anything, and nothing asynchronous can happen that might try to use the stack while you have `rsp` not pointing at the stack.  Seriously, it's really rare for even hand-written performance-tuned asm to use the stack pointer for anything but the normal use, so really just forget I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to swap two double word values within two different arrays and you want to do this using two registers. You are loading `EAX`and `EDI` with two values (one from each array), after you swap the register values you need to store/save them back into their respective array offsets in memory for their values to change. So continuing your line of code, try:

```
Push Eax
Mov  Eax, Edi
Pop  Edi
Mov  dword ptr[esi + 4 + edx * 4], Eax
Mov  dword ptr[esi + edx * 4], Edi
```

You can leave out the dword ptr type override prefix when the destination operand is an extended register, I believe it will be assumed that the source value will be the same size (double word). So this will also work:

```
mov eax, [esi + edx * 4]  
mov edi, [esi + 4 + edx * 4]
```

Also, do you have to use that mode of addressing? It seems you are using indirect indexed displacement addressing.